# AWS MSK + S3 Sink - JSON Messages getting stored as Structs instead of JSON

Tags: apache-kafka, apache-kafka-connect, debezium

I'm doing some Postgres CDC work using Debezium, AWS MSK + MSK Connect, and an S3 Sink.  I have a working configuration for both Debezium + the S3 Sink below.  All the permissions + connection stuff is set up already.

The databases changes are getting captured & stored to S3 as JSON files, but in the file itself the messages seem to be Structs (see below).

[image]

I'm expecting the messages to look like this (proper JSON format).

[image]

Debezium Config

```
connector.class=io.debezium.connector.postgresql.PostgresConnector
database.user=user
database.dbname=test_db
database.server.id=5400
tasks.max=1
transforms=unwrap,dropTopicPrefix
database.server.name=dev_postgres
schema.include.list=test
transforms.dropTopicPrefix.regex=dev_postgres.test.(.*)
database.port=5432
plugin.name=pgoutput
include.schema.changes=true
transforms.dropTopicPrefix.replacement=$1
database.hostname=host
database.password=xxx
transforms.unwrap.type=io.debezium.transforms.ExtractNewRecordState
transforms.dropTopicPrefix.type=org.apache.kafka.connect.transforms.RegexRouter
```

S3 Config

```
connector.class=io.confluent.connect.s3.S3SinkConnector
s3.region=us-east-1
flush.size=65536
schema.compatibility=NONE
tasks.max=1
topics=reservation,reservation2
timezone=UTC
format.class=io.confluent.connect.s3.format.json.JsonFormat
partitioner.class=io.confluent.connect.storage.partitioner.DefaultPartitioner
schema.generator.class=io.confluent.connect.storage.hive.schema.DefaultSchemaGenerator
storage.class=io.confluent.connect.s3.storage.S3Storage
key.converter=org.apache.kafka.connect.storage.StringConverter
s3.bucket.name=bucket
rotate.schedule.interval.ms=60000
```

I'm doing some drop topic prefix stuff in Debezium so the topic names become just the names of the table.

The only other thing to note is you have to define a default worker config in MSK, so i've been using this one.  Not sure if it's impacting this or causing it to get screwed up.

[image]

I imagine there's some key or value converter I screwed up somewhere to get these messages to store as JSON but I can't figure it out.  If anyone can have a look and point in the right direction I'd appreciate it !

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to use JSONConverter rather than StringConverter in the sink. Ideally, you'd have Debezium doing the same, so you can set a default in the worker properties, or override in each connector, up to you...

Otherwise, it will `toString` the Connect Struct objects

Comment: that makes sense to me.  I added `key.converter=org.apache.kafka.connect.json.JsonConverter` to both the Debezium + S3 Sink configurations, but now I'm getting `Caused by: org.apache.kafka.connect.errors.DataException: Converting byte[] to Kafka Connect data failed due to serialization error:` and 
`Caused by: org.apache.kafka.common.errors.SerializationException: com.fasterxml.jackson.core.JsonParseException: Unrecognized token 'Struct': was expecting (JSON String, Number, Array, Object or token 'null', 'true' or 'false')` errors in the S3 Sink.  Do I have to add value.converter stuff too?

Comment: @jyablonski Hey did you fix this error?

Comment: @Kay As answered, `StringConverter` will output string-records like `"Struct{...}"` which is not proper JSON. Therefore JSON parsers will fail. This applies to both key and value converters

Comment: ye im looking into this right now, and using JSONConverter converts it to json. thanks